# jquery custom validation (addMethod) returning false regardless

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

I'm beating my head against the wall on this one, so I appreciate any help on this.  I have some a validation method I created to point to a javascript function that return true/false if the email isn't/is currently in our membership table.  The javascript function (CheckEmail) works great, the controller action works fine, but regardless of true or false being return by CheckEmail, it always evaluates to an invalid field.  Please help:

validation

```
 $.validator.addMethod("emailCheck", function (value, element) {
                return this.optional(element) || CheckEmail(value);
            }, "This email is already registered");

            Validator = $("#RegForm").validate({
                rules: {
                    Email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true,
                        emailCheck: true
                    },
                    Password: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 6
                    },
                    ConfirmPassword: {
                        required: true,
                        equalTo: "#Password"
                    },
                    "UserObj.FirstName": {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 2
                    },
                    "UserObj.LastName": {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 2
                    }
                }

            });
```

javascript method:

```
function CheckEmail(email) {
    $.getJSON("/account/jsonCheckEmail", { EmailToCheck: email }, function (data) {
        if (data.status = "OK") {
            if (data.msg = "True") {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

}
```

controller action:

```
public JsonNetResult jsonCheckEmail(string EmailToCheck)
{
    JsonNetResult jsonEmail = new JsonNetResult();
    jsonEmail.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    try
    {

        string user = Membership.GetUserNameByEmail(EmailToCheck);

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user))
        {
            jsonEmail.Data = new jsonResponseObj("True", "True");
        }
        else {
            jsonEmail.Data = new jsonResponseObj("False","False");
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        jsonEmail.Data = new jsonResponseObj(ex);
        //jsonEmail.Data = new jsonResponseObj("False", "False");
    }

    return jsonEmail;
}
```

HTML:

```
               <tr>
                    <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
                    </td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: @user....could it be related to 'return this.optional(element)'. Try removing that code and see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than write your own jQuery handler, you could leverage the plugin's [remote](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote#options) facility:

```
Email: {
     required: true,
     email: true,
     remote: "/account/jsonCheckEmail"
},
```